# Display product video in product description tab

Tags: magento2, product-view

I am using magento 2.0.7 and I want to display the product video/image and product description (in product description tab) in view page.

Answer (score 2):

simply render that block and template in detail tab

Add the below line in `<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml` before end of div tag

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

The output is look like below may be your styling get different because I do some LESS work for my image view.
[image: easy for your reference]

Comment: not working.. js errors  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnCurrentImages' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial will help you add your Magento product video under the product name programmatically.

First, create "video" attribute as text input.

Jump to the following file.

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and find the following code in the above file.

```
<div class="product-name">
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Now insert the following code.

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<?php endif; ?>
```

To display the video, you just have to paste the video Unique Identifier into the video attribute field.

Answer (score 0):

New tab in product detail page is very easy task with product attribute. Use below steps and check it out.

**Step 1.** Create Product Attribute

> video

.

**Step 2.** Create file “catalog_product_view.xml” in the app/design/frontend/{vender name}/{theme name}/Magento_Catalog/layout

In the file write the below code:

```
    <!-- this is code to add new tab start -->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.video" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getVideo</argument>
<argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">video</argument>
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">video</argument>
<argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Video</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
<!-- this is code to add new tab end -->
```

Hope it will work for you.